# warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in

Tags: ubercart

I have migrated a site from one host to another and I now get the following warning:

> warning: `number_format()` expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in /var/www/vhosts/vinylletters.biz/httpdocs/modules/uc_font_attribute/uc_font_attribute.module on line 74.

Line 74 is the following.

```
$html .= '<div class="font-block-url-'.$key.'"><span class="font-url">'.$fontValue->fontValue.'</span><span class="preview-url">'.str_replace('.ttf','.png',$fontValue->fontValue).'</span><span class="extra-price">'.number_format($fontValue->price,2,'.','').'</span></div>';
```

I am not sure what I need to do to get this line working.

Comment: This sounds like it should be in ubercart module's issue queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `number_format()` function requires a *float* type variable for its first parameter.

Try casting the parameter like this:

```
$html .= '<div class="font-block-url-'.$key.'"><span class="font-url">'.$fontValue->fontValue.'</span><span class="preview-url">'.str_replace('.ttf','.png',$fontValue->fontValue).'</span><span class="extra-price">'.number_format((float)($fontValue->price),2,'.','').'</span></div>';
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for that when i tried it my whole site just goes white so dont think that is the answer

Comment: Might be the second parentheses. Try just `(float) $fontValue->price` . The alternative would be to process the variable outsde the line (eg. `$mynumber = $fontValue->price;` ), and then to insert your new variable into the line for the `number_format((float)$mynumber,....)` function.

Comment: It all works now i had missed out ( Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad to help. @Pax is right. You should put this into the issue queue for the uc_font_attribute module.